# Google maps v2 android move map to markers

Tags: android, google-maps, markers

I have searched this topic a lot, but haven't found the solution I need.

I have a database of markers which appear on the map fragment.
I display a recycler view of these markers in a view below the fragment.
I want the user to click on the list item, and the map will move to that location.
I have been using this:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(tempMarker.getPosition(), DEFAULT_ZOOM))
```

This works for me. (tempMarker is the marker I want to move to) However this only relocates the map to that exact position, however the marker is not focused. i.e the title of the marker does not show. How can I move the map to that marker, so that the marker will be focused and the title will show.

Thank you.

Comment: You will need to set the title for the new marker! Perhaps what you could do is clear the map of any existing markers then add the newer marker with title;

Comment: There are lots of markers on the map. To move to the map to one marker and show its title, it seems incorrect to wipe all the markers off the map, and re-add them just to do this.

Comment: I thought you had one marker! Sorry about that. Well, when  a user selects one item from the list, then you can set or add the marker and move the camera accordingly;

Comment: If I understand your question you just need to call `tempMarker.showInfoWindow();` after `mMap.animateCamera()`

Comment: antonio - brilliant. Thanks very much!